# HiveQL ALTER TABLE: NullPointerException, INSERT INTO: MISSING table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm having trouble with the `INSERT INTO` and `ALTER TABLE` commands. I found the following code in my notes, which indicates it probably worked at some point. However, it isn't working now. Can anyone point out mistakes?

```
DROP TABLE anyoung.toytable_docs;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS anyoung.toytable_docs
(
  id INT COMMENT 'unique document ID', 
  rev INT,
  content STRING
)
COMMENT 'Employee details';
```

Both of the following also fail:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE anyoung.toytable_docs (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'The earth is flat'),
  ('2', '1', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('1', '2', 'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn'),
  ('1', '3', 'The earth is like a ball.');

use anyoung;
INSERT INTO TABLE toytable_docs (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'The earth is flat'),
  ('2', '1', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('1', '2', 'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn'),
  ('1', '3', 'The earth is like a ball.');
```

with: `FAILED: ParseException line 1:32 cannot recognize input near 'VALUES' '(' ''1'' in select clause`

When I attempt an `ALTER TABLE` command, both of the following failed:

```
ALTER TABLE anyoung.toytable_docs CHANGE content content STRING COMMENT 'The actual contents of the document';

use anyoung;
ALTER TABLE toytable_docs CHANGE content content STRING COMMENT 'The actual contents of the document';
```

Anyone have any insights? I already Googled/SO, etc.

Comment: And what is the error when you are doing ALTER ?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to insert from select:

```
with your_data as(
select stack(4,
'1', '1', 'The earth is flat',
'2', '1', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin',
'1', '2', 'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn',
'1', '3', 'The earth is like a ball.'
) as (id, rev, content)
)

use anyoung;
INSERT INTO TABLE toytable_docs 
select id, rev, content from your_data;
```

Comment: I made that mistake in my post but not my actual code. The error is actually: `FAILED: ParseException line 1:32 cannot recognize input near 'VALUES' '(' ''1'' in select clause`. That error is generated both by my code, and a copy-paste of your solution above.